# Update database on browser closing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to limit users from being logged in on more than one machine at a time. To do this I am changing the value of a field in my database to `1` upon login and resetting it back to `0` in the `LogOff()` method of `AccountController`.

I would like the user to be automatically logged out when the browser is closed so I set `inPersistent = false` at logging in like so:

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
```

The problem is that when the browser is closed the `LogOff()` method isn't called and I am unable to reset my value to 0. Since the field has not been reset to 0, that user won't be able to log in again.

How can I update my database and reset that field to 0 when the browser is closed?

Comment: What would happen when the browser or the OS crashes?

Comment: the user gets logged out, I suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this doesn't answer your question regarding the browser shut down, this issue could be solved with the use of the Identity `SecurityStamp` .

Upon user login you could force update the `SecurityStamp` which would in turn invalidate any other valid cookies and allow the user to only be signed in on *one* machine at a time.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320551/1454538) explains the `SecurityStamp` perfectly.

> So the primary purpose of the `SecurityStamp` is to enable sign out everywhere. The basic idea is that whenever something security related is changed on the user, like a password, it is a good idea to automatically invalidate any existing sign in cookies, so if your password/account was previously compromised, the attacker no longer has access.
>
> In 2.0.0 we added the following configuration to hook the
>   `OnValidateIdentity` method in the CookieMiddleware to look at the
>   `SecurityStamp` and reject cookies when it has changed. It also
>   automatically refreshes the user's claims from the database every
>   refreshInterval if the stamp is unchanged (which takes care of things
>   like changing roles etc)

If that is route you're wanting to go; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320551/1454538) explains exactly how to accomplish what you're looking for (end result) in *good detail*.

---

I will provide the source code from that post for *clarity*.

Basically your login method would look like this.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(model);
}


// check if username/password pair match.
var loggedinUser = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
if (loggedinUser != null)
{
    // change the security stamp only on correct username/password
    await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(loggedinUser.Id);
}

 // do sign-in
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
        return View("Lockout");
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
    case SignInStatus.Failure:
    default:
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
}
```

}

And you would update your ConfigureAuth method in `Startup.Auth.cs`

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    // other stuff
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0), // <-- Note the timer is set for zero
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad way of developing things. Why won't you use slidingExpiration on cookies to invalidate a cookie.

If you want to check for unique users, you should check for the last used session and invalidate the session used before.

Is that a good alternative?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds good. But wouldn't the sliding expiration works when Formas Authentication mode is "FORMS", I have got it on net that Forms authentication is obsolete so, In my config file I have set <authentication mode="None" />. ??

Comment: Sliding expiration can be manually implemented. It just means that when the client hits the server ( eg. catch this with a http module or with a Attribute on your controller), then get the ExpirationValue of the cookie and then add some time to it. I personally have a project which stores every session and every page. When a user has the same UserAgent and IP as a previous session, i invalidate the previous session so the user gets logged out ( just mentioning, you can adjust it to your needs)

Answer (score 0):

Look for `onbeforeunload` and make an asynchronous call to your server endpoint to do execute the necessary code.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
  alert("browser closing")
  // to do : Call server 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript event as below:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
       // write code here
    }
};
```