# Cannot set AuthenticationType in CookieAuthenticationOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to implement the solution proposed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831295/prevent-multiple-logins) user for prevent multiple logins in my application.

Actually I declared in my `Startup` class, specifically in the `Configure` method this code:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{

});
```

the problem is that when I type: `AuthenticationType` I get nothing displayed, because `CookieAuthenticationOptions` doesn't have this property, and this is weird because also in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.1) the property doesn't exists anymore.

If I hover the mouse on `CookieAuthenticationOptions` I can see this namespace: `Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies`.

**PS: I'm using ASP.NET CORE**

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Core are you using? Note that the linked question is not about ASP.NET **Core** but about classic ASP.NET MVC. Solutions for the latter will generally not work on Core.

Comment: the version of ASP.CORE you are targeting is relevant, yes. The question you're referencing to was likely not ASP.NET Core 2.0+.  Note, there was aspnet announcement on this (here is the draft for it): https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1310

Comment: As others have noted the example you're linking to is not for ASP.NET Core.  You need to find a more recent example.  Also, the entire authentication module was completely overhauled in ASP.NET Core 2.0 so you'll need to find examples for that version.  Try starting with the official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: I'm using `ASP.NET Core 2.1`, and I actually learning it, so I don't no the difference with the previous versions. Someone have a fresh example on this type of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.UseCookieAuthentication()` is deprecated ASP.NET Core 2.X, you should use `app.UseAuthentication()` in the `Configure` method instead, however you'll need to configure the authentication inside the `ConfigureServices` method.

Using NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` version 2.1.0 or later it should be configured like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add the needed services, e.g. services.AddMvc();

    services
        .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            // Change the options as needed
        });            
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Martin, the only thing that I don't understand is how your code can prevent the multiple login, could you explain this? Or maybe you have missed something?

Comment: This doesn't handle the issue with preventing multiple logins, but only enables you to change the cookie options, which is also needed by looking at the linked question.

Comment: The problem's that I cannot find the property `AuthenticationType ` inside the `options.`, and also the others seems no more available

Comment: The AutenticationType is moved into `AddAuthentication` and if I remember correctly is now `DefaultScheme`. For the others look at the `options.Events` inside AddCookie()

Answer (score 0):

1- double click on your project

2- in `<item group>` Add the following line:

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`