# Restrict (Prevent) user to login multiple times using same credentials in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, multiple-login

I am using microsoft login (Azure ad) in my asp.net core application. I want to restrict same user from multiple logins from different devices or places.
Whats the way?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate question. You may find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831295/prevent-multiple-logins

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent multiple logins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831295/prevent-multiple-logins)

Comment: doesn't work when the user closes the browser without logging out.