# Stop Users Concurrently Signing In Via Different Machines - Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am using Identity Server 4 with the quickstart UI and a client using Cookie Authentication.

Lets say I have `user A` on `machine A` who is currently logged in via the browser.  Then `user A` decides to go on `machine B` and logs into that one.  As it stands, a new session cookie will be issued for user A on `machine B` as well as `machine A`.

This is fine, but I want the option to mark particular users with a flag e.g. `IsConcurrent` and if it is set to `true`, they will be given the option to either keep their existing session on `machine A`, or terminate it and start a new session on `machine B`.

I have done some reading and found references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831295/prevent-multiple-logins) to updating the security stamp for a user and setting the interval to zero, so it checks the security stamp in the cookie against the stored version.  However, this code didn't seem to be inline with Identity Server's code.  Also, it it a valid option in this case?

I also found [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/736) which mentions storing and checking the value of session IDs, but I'm not sure if this is valid either?

An initial idea was to implement some middleware that obtained the Machine ID and stored it in a table along with the user, but then I was unsure how to take something like this any further.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming cookie based authentication, you can extend the *client* to validate the user session provided that the client keeps track of user sessions.

For that you can create a session manager where you add a session for the user (sub) after login, this also includes automatic login sessions (SSO). Remove one or all sessions on logout, which should also be updated on back channel logout (`LogoutCallback`).

Assuming you use middleware, you can consult the session manager there and decide what to do. Make sure that the current session isn't already activated after login. It has to step through the middleware at least once. Some pseudo code to illustrate the idea:

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext context, SessionManager sessionManager)
{
    if (context.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var sub = context.Principal.FindFirst("sub")?.Value;
        var sid = context.Principal.FindFirst("sid")?.Value;

        // User is allowed when the current session is active.
        if (!sessionManager.CurrentSessionIsActive(sub, sid))
        {
            // Rewrite path if user needs and is allowed to choose: redirect to session selector or
            // Activate the current session and deactivate other sessions, if any.
            if (sessionManager.HasMultipleSessions(sub) && sessionManager.CanSelectSession(sub))
                context.Request.Path = new PathString("/SelectSession");
            else
                sessionManager.ActivateCurrentSession(sub, sid);
        }
    }
    return _next(context);
}
```

On post of the SelectSession form you can mark in the session manager which sessions are active. If the old session should be preserved, then ignore the old session (remains active) and mark the current session as active.

Make sure to add the middleware after authenticating the user.

Please note that for access tokens you'll need a different strategy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have also up-voted it.  Yes its cookie based authentication and I have edited my post to reflect this.  I understand some of this but I am unsure how the `SelectSession` comes in to play.  Is this the page I mentioned where the user will get the option to end other sessions?  Will I still need a flag on the user as I want this to apply to specific users and not all of them.

Comment: Upon research, I cannot find a `SessionManager` class - only a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session` where you use the `HttpContext.Session.SetString` and `HttpContext.Session.GetString`.  What is your sudo `SessionManager`?

Comment: SessionManager is a custom implementation. A [singleton](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreBackChannelLogout/blob/master/MvcHybridBackChannel/Startup.cs#L32) to keep track of the sessions. Here's [a sample](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreBackChannelLogout/blob/master/MvcHybridBackChannel/CookieEventHandler.cs) that uses the CookieAuthenticationEvents, calling a [LogoutSessionManager](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreBackChannelLogout/blob/master/MvcHybridBackChannel/LogoutSessionManager.cs). Take this as start and adjust it to your requirements.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense.  Thanks, I'll take a look and mark your answer as correct as it looks like its on the right lines in terms of what we need.