# how to restrict multiple login of the user

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, abp

We want to restrict users to multiple login sessions at a time, there should be a single active login session.

Users should be allowed to be logged in to one application from only one browser at a time. When the user log in the server should check his current active sessions to the same application from other browsers. If there is then log out from everywhere else and keep only the newest session.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent multiple logins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831295/prevent-multiple-logins)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net Core's default authentication cookie middleware has a handy hook (via the `CookieAuthenticationOptions.SessionStore` property and `ITicketStore` interface) to allow you to implement custom backend storage for the cookie payload (claims). The end result is a protected cookie containing just basic AuthenticationProperties values and the session ID as a claim and everything else stored in the DB, keyed off the user ID and session ID etc.

With this in place you can automatically invalidate any existing session for a given user account (the ID of which being an indexed field/property in your backing store) by deleting or otherwise expiring any other sessions.

This also has the advantage of allowing you to invalidate sessions based on other circumstances like a password or other security settings changing.

You could also implement something to trigger back channel logout calls to client applications if you also track which clients they've signed into in the given session in the backing store too.

*Note:* The SessionStore property is a singleton concurrently accessed instance so ensure your implementation handles database connectivity appropriately if you go this route. Note also that the wireup is best done via an implementation of `IPostConfigureOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>`

Answer (score 1):

Change the security stamp `SecurityStamp.AbpUsers` when the user logins.
The previous logins becomes invalid.

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/4821#issuecomment-524732321